# How to set screen size between 4' and 10'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have Samsung Galaxy S2 and Samsung Note 10.1. I create on S2 first, now I try to run on Note10.1 but it is not same screen size. I need to make screen of note10.1 to look like  S2.

I try to put big picture into xhdpi, but it use picture in hdpi, in every screen size.

Galaxy S2

[image]

Note 10.1

[image]

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<project.kmutt.Action_bar_view
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="979px"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:columnWidth="90px"
    android:numColumns="3" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10px"

    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="30px" >
</GridView>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/web" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/setting" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/about" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Home" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Website" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Setting" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="About" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

create a different layout folder for one of the two sizes. These are the possible folder structures you can create.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Android will look for the `my_layout.xml` file in the right folder according to what device it is running on. If it cant find a specific folder (for example `layout-xlarge`) it will use the `my_layout.xml` file from the default `res/layout/` folder.

You can find more info on this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

And avoid using LinearLayouts too often. RelativeLayouts will be a lot better if you create one layout file for multiple screens.

Comment: +1. This answer is almost perfect, just remember that layout-small, -large and the like aren't best practice, you should define categories based on width and/or height. See android developers guidelines for better insight.